# is DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() secure?

Tags: php

Can someone inject some malicious code into my script through this method? and if someone might, what is the best practice?

I am trying to create a similar to reddit way of suggesting title.

Answer (score 1):

The really short answer is **YES**. Generically speaking, any "foreign" loading of HTML is insecure - indeed, any loading of **any** data from a user is potentially insecure - all user supplied data **must** be validated and vetted.

However, It isn't really possible to give a definitive answer based on the information you have supplied. This is because it depends on which file, how is the file controlled, what do you do with the file once it is loaded.

Add this information and maybe I can give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you're asking about the security of that function/method you're talking about injecting some code that will be executed on the server and not `XSS`.

I'm not a `C`/`C++` expert, but looking at [`dom_load_html()`'s source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/dom/document.c#L2152) which is the method behind `loadHTMLFile()` I can see it's following well-structured logic and the flow is well controlled in addition to failing safely whenever encountering a problem.

Again, I'm a novice and you probably need some expert on `C`/`C++`, and the above is just my personal opinion.

Answer (score -1):

There is at least one security problem with this:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/XML_External_Entity_Processing

The above page says that the XML standard defines a way to specify external enitities which can specify an URL to load data from. It could load data from local ressources as well.

The xml libraries of PHP use libxml2, which by default implement that behaviour. There is a way to disable it, but this will also disable some other functions of the library. The best way ist just to disable it for the methods loadXML() and loadHTML():

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $oldValue = libxml_disable_entity_loader( true );
    $dom->loadXML( $xml );
    libxml_disable_entity_loader( $oldValue );
```